# How to count only specific values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe;

```
a = [['01', '12345', 'null'], ['02', '78910', '9870'], ['01', '23456', 'null'],['01', '98765', '8760']]

df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['id', 'order', 'location'])
```

I need to get a count of how many NULL values (NULL is a string) that occur for each ID. So the result would look like;

```
id   null_count
01    02
```

I can get basic counts using a groupby:

```
new_df = df_a.groupby(['id', 'location'])['id'].count()
```

But the results return more than just the NULL values;

```
id  location
01  8760        1
    null        2
02  9870        1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your source dataframe your NULLs are strings 'null', use:

```
df_a.groupby('id')['location'].apply(lambda x: (x=='null').sum())\
    .reset_index(name='null_count')
```

Output:

```
   id  null_count
0  01          2
1  02          0
```

OR

```
df_a.query('location == "null"').groupby('id')['location'].size()\
    .reset_index(name='null_count')
```

Output:

```
   id  null_count
0  01           2
```

Comment: I am wishing you a Merry Christmas! And thank you for all support, so small present for you (3+). Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Base on your own code , adding `.loc` notice this is multi index slice ..

```
df_a.groupby(['id', 'location'])['id'].count().loc[:,'null']
Out[932]: 
id
01    2
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [16]: df_a.set_index('id')['location'].eq('null').sum(level=0)
Out[16]:
id
01    2.0
02    0.0
Name: location, dtype: float64
```